# Hardware logs storage?

Tags: server, configuration, log, administration, syslog

I have a Ubuntu Server 11.10 installed. wanted to know where hardware related logs are stored & is there any configuration that needs to be done, for those logs to be activated?

If possible please mention where to find the logs related to drivers of the respective hardware failuer or something related to particular driver failure?

And in case if they are stored in one single log file then how to distinguish the hardware errors or logs from drivers errors or logs?

**My purpose behind this information :**
          I am just going to keep record of all those logs and audit those logs for ISO 27001 and then will send E-mails to respective Server Administrators for the errors that are found and errors that are occurring again and again. **I am not looking for any particular hardware log here**, but just would be auditing those logs and making sure that they are stored for 3 months on central storage server for future references. but still is there are any hardware related issues or errors that have occurred then would like to have then reviewed in the audit.

**Update**
  I am going to keep all the log files mentioned below for the audit but if any one of you think that I have to include some more log files for tracking hardware issues in the audit please suggest. :

/var/log/messages : General log messages

/var/log/boot : System boot log

/var/log/auth.log : User login and authentication logs

/var/log/daemon.log : Running services such as squid, ntpd and others log message to this file

/var/log/dpkg.log : All binary package log includes package installation and other information

/var/log/faillog : User failed login log file

/var/log/kern.log : Kernel log file

/var/log/mysql.* : MySQL server log file

/var/log/user.log : All userlevel logs

/var/log/fsck/* : fsck command log

/var/log/apport.log : Application crash report / log file

**Updated Question TITLE**

Thanks a log for the support till now and thanking you all for the same! :)

Warm Regards,

Rishee

Comment: What kind of hardware related logs are you looking for? `/var/log/messages` contains also hardware related error messages from the kernel.

Comment: Hi Lumbric, I am just going to keep record of all those logs and audit those logs for ISO 27001 and then will send E-mails to respective Server Administrators for the errors that are found and errors that are occurring again and again. Thanks for you quick response. :)

Comment: I don't know if the log I mentioned provides a complete list of hardware problems. There might be something bigger. I suspect there is not one log, but you'll have to enable several specific montitoring abilities for the different hardware parts. But maybe somebody else knows more than I do. On the other hand: probably you are not the first one who tries to do something like this.

Comment: Hi Lumbric, Thanks a lot! I have added the List of log files that I am auditing on each server for the hardware related issues and errors and warning in which I have added the log file that you suggested. So please go through that list, I've also mentioned the purpose of that log file in front of it. Please feel free to advice me to and some more log files or modify that list. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing this for [ISO/IEC 27001](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_27001) perhaps you should consider setting up a central syslog server and having all your client machines forward their logs onto this computer.

Ubuntu uses Rsyslog and [their wiki has several examples](http://wiki.rsyslog.com/index.php/Configuration_Samples) of possible configurations. The [failover sample](http://wiki.rsyslog.com/index.php/FailoverSyslogServer) is probably most relevant.

Comment: We have a centralized log storage server were logs are stored but I am not sure which log files to take, for auditing the Hardware related issues, that is why, I need to know which log files I need to audit for that reason. Thanks for your response. :)

Comment: I have never used that website and have never heard about it. So is that website link trust worthy, to take use the configuration that they have suggested on the servers?                                     @lumbric