# How to get logs/evidence of illegal hardware changes during laptop repairs

Tags: hardware, cpu, logs

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04. I sent my laptop for repair and I find out that the CPU has been changed to a cheaper version without my consent (and I was not requesting to fix the cpu at all!), basically from i7 to AMD Ryzen 5 Pro 2500 U

I've read from online that there are logs for hardware changes in Ubuntu. Where is the commands in terminal? I see people listing [a list of log](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113182/hardware-logs-storage) but I'm not sure which one indicates such change.

Alternatively, I'm thinking about checking the drivers or firmware, but now sure where to begin and how exactly.

I beg for all the possible ways as I will forward the evidence to the police. Thank you everyone!

p.s. my account is password protected. They should be unable to change the firmware within I suppose? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: does [this resource](https://linuxhandbook.com/check-cpu-info-linux/) help?

Comment: There is no *specific* logging of hardware changes.  You'll want to run `lshw` before your system goes out and then after and then compare.  If your *laptop* has been repaired though, there's limits on technology due to motherboards all being different, so if your system has a different processor and such now it probably is *not* the same laptop.  Checking drivers requires you to know what packages are installed on your computer before and after.  "Firmware" as in system board firmware will be different if motherboards changed.  After all, Intel and AMD sockets aren't interchangeable.

Comment: The proper way to handle this is to document what you handed in by e.g. purchase receipt compared to what you got back. Not logs from your system.

Answer (score 4):

By using `journalctl`, you can watch your system boot, and discover the hardware. By using `sudo journalctl  --list-boots`, you can see how far back in time the logs go. Then, use the `-b` option to pick which one to look at. Read `man journalctl` and click on my userid beneath this answer. I have some `journalctl` hints in my Profile.

Do something like:

```
# specify how many. 
# 0 is this boot, 
# -1 is previous boot 
# -2 is the boot before that
# the negation (`-` sign) is handled below
bootstart=6
bootend=2
for boot in $(seq $bootstart $bootend ); do
    sudo journalctl  -b -$boot
done
```

Pick the last reboot when your system was in your hands, inspect that one, and any boots done since then, by you or the repair shop.

Comment: This is very cool.